# Repast: call initialization during runtime

Tags: repast-simphony

I have previously built a model to run by each day independently. During the start of the day the initialization procedure will be conducted to read input data and perform all initialization things related to this day.

Now I am considering to run multiple days at one time. So at the start of the next day, I need to call the initialization again to refresh the data relevant to this new day.

How to call initialization during runtime? is it possible to do so?
if not, what's the best workaround?